# How to Share the State of an Object across different Instances?

Tags: swift, state, observers

**Hey**, 
I am trying to improve my development skills and came across some difficulties. I read about Observers in Swift on SwiftBySundell.com and now want to improve the app I am currently working on.

The app is simple: You press a button and a Time Stamp is saved into a CoreData Database.

So I got a View with a Button and a Model with some functionality. 
To my mind, when pressing the button, the state of my model (TimeMachine) should go from lets say .idle to .started.

I have added some code below on how I could achieve this w.o. observers.

Now, while Sundell is explaining what I would have to do to implement Observers (in like 4 different ways) I seem to be missing some understanding on what actually happens.

Especially when I want to create a new view, that will also create an instance of TimeMachine. (Is this not the way to do it? Should I pass the object to the view instead of creating a new one?)

**To sum up my question:** How do I accieve best a shared state of my TimeMachine across my views? AND even with observers in place, do they only work over the same instance of the class?

**Edit:** I do know what an object is and that two instances are different.
However, there would be the possibility to create a static variable for example?
I am just trying to figure out the correct way to do things.

Do I realy have to pass along the tM, each time I sague to the next view?

```swift
import Foundation

class TimeMachine {
    var state = State.idle {
        didSet { stateDidChange() }
    }

    func stateDidChange() {
        print("The State is now \(state)")
    }

    enum State{
        case idle
        case started
        case paused
    }
}

let tM = TimeMachine()
let tM2 = TimeMachine()

tM.state = .idle
//The State is now idle
tM.state = .started
//The State is now started

print("tM2 State is: \(tM2.state)")
//tM2 State is: idle
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the whole idea of references. You have two different instances of some class. You can't expect that on second instance will be called observer of some property when you set property on first instance. These instances have nothing common.

Since classes are reference types, you can pass references of **same** instance of your `TimeMachine` across your views. You can use methods, closures, variables, ...

So, you need same instance

```
let tM = TimeMachine()
tM.state = .started // prints "The State is now \(state)"
```

Comment: Hey, yes this concept I do understand! I just thought there is a different way. 
So creating the tM instance and then passing it along to the next view (and back again?) is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @UMPUSTEN hey, it depends on lot of stuff. There are too many options...

Comment: What other option is there? Do you by any chance have something I can read that explains to better understand?

Comment: @UMPUSTEN maybe in your question describe better your actual problem

Comment: There is no "problem" to speak off. Just the case that I want to add a different view that should know the state of my TimeMachine. So is currently time beeing "recorded" or not. (Lets say maybe I want to show a little timer in the next view of seconds passed since I pressed the button.)

If this dose not explain my question better I'll try to upload my code later tonight.

Comment: maybe I would like to add that I tried to figure out a better way then to always "prepare for segue" and send everything back and forth

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to know how to "correctly" share state across your app, in this case your TimeMachine instance? There are alot of ways of going about it, here are a few ways.

Using Dependency Injection:

- Pass the object on navigation
- Use a Dependency Injection library, or write your own one.

Generate a correct TimeMachine instance from the available data. (I do not think this is possible in this use case though).

Use a singleton, extending your TimeMachine to contain a static shared variable.

```
class TimeMachine {
    static let TimeMachine shared = TimeMachine()

    var state = State.idle {
        didSet { stateDidChange() }
    }

    func stateDidChange() {
        print("The State is now \(state)")
    }

    enum State{
        case idle
        case started
        case paused
    }
}
```

IMHO you should just pass the reference to the TimeMachine object in this case. Also I do not think the Observer pattern is really applicable in this question, unless i am misunderstanding part of it.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for your answer. 
I think you understood me correctly to a point. 
Let me try to be a bit more specific: One of the ways described by Sundell here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/observers-in-swift-part-1?rq=observ is using protocols as observers. Now every class that is using the observer protocol can subscribe to any changes made to the state. However, I am unsure how this change of state is passed back and noticed by the class. (For me this information is missing in his blogpost. I fear I lack some background knowledge). Maybe I should've lead with this.

Comment: While my use case is small I am ok with "overdoing" it. Im just trying to get better and somewhere I have to start ;)

Comment: Oh ok. First of all you dont use protocols as observers, you specify a contract (in swift a protocol or in OOP terminology an "interface"), which a class/instantiated object conforms to. Object Q implements Protocol W, which promises that a function "print() -> String" exists.

In short it means, in this case, that a Object A has a list of objects, all of which have a function "didStartPlaying". Object A can then iterate over and call "didStartPlaying" on each of these objects. I would recommend looking into some textbooks about OOP :)

Comment: Hi, in the example his class adds an observer to its own instance of the AudioPlayer (player.addObserver(self)). Now the "player" instance has a id of the class and can iterate over when the state changes. **However,** this still only works in the same instance of the AudioPlayer?!! An other isntance will not have the observations dictionary with all observer id's....So where is the purpose for doing it in the first place? I would still have to share the instance in some other way...then I could just check the state myself without all the work. What am i missing?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the patterns purpose, the purpose of the Observer pattern is to get state updates when you dont know when to "ask" an object for the state. 

For example, when you have an AudioPlayer, and want to show a menu when the user presses stop. You _could_ create a polling mechanism, that checks the state of the AudioPlayer instance every millisecond, and show a menu when `isStopped=false`. As you understand, this is a waste of resources, and a lot harder to follow. This is where the Observer pattern comes in.

Comment: Hey, yes I got it now. Thank you so much.
I got confuzed and mixed two things totgehet.

I posted below some Explanation alswell